# Links to answers in a comment on the same page should resolve to anchor links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, hyperlinks

When there is a comment to a question, you can easily get a link to it from its timestamp, and when pressed, it will make the page go to its anchor and highlight it without reloading the page.

But a link to another answer *on the same question page*, generated from the "share" link under the post, looks like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530531/1306322
```

which, when posted in a comment, question or answer looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530531/1306322, and, when clicked, causes the page to *reload* even though the link ends up *on the same page*. A round-trip to the server is needed to redirect you back to where you started out.

The link could instead be transformed into this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525250/tint-a-particular-color-in-xna#15530531
```

which is already automatically given a title when used in a post: [Tint a particular color in XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525250/tint-a-particular-color-in-xna#15530531)

This link URL matches the current page but has an anchor in it, so clicking on it avoids a server roundtrip and page reload.

The shorter link will certainly look better for example on twitter, but it's not as good on the SE sites, especially in case it's used in the same question it leads to.

Comment: As a workaround, one can create the link in the format of your proposed transformation target oneself and avoid the page reload for all users who visited a link to the question. 
(It still leads to a page reload for users following a link to an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the intention of this feature request, but would propose that the links should rather be transformed into just the subpart marker. For the example in the question, it would be just this:

```
#15530531
```

The advantage is that it avoids a page reload on every of the URL aliases of a question's page. When considering aliases, we only need to count those that do not redirect to a "canonical" URL, but it still leaves us with one URL for the question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525250/tint-a-particular-color-in-xna
```

and one URL for each answer, which is reached by following a link given under "Share" for each answer. In this case we have two answers, so these two links:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525250/tint-a-particular-color-in-xna/15530531#15530531
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525250/tint-a-particular-color-in-xna/15525980#15525980
```

(On a related note, a valid workaround would be creating the subpart marker link yourself if Markdown would allow it. It doesn't, but that's for another feature request.)